# What's the Complexity when range varies?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, complexity-theory

What is the complexity if you have an algorithm like this:

```
int get(const std::vector<unsigned int>& v, int N)
{
    int a = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j)
            for(int k = 0; k < v[j]; ++k)
                a += k * v[j];
    return a;
}
```

Besides the missing usefullness, what do you put into the complexity if one factor is varying that much? I mean, it's surely `O(N * V * ?)`, when `V = v.size()`, but what then?

Comment: Do you have any hint on the range of `v`'s elements? Without further context this might be hard to answer. Surely it is bounded by `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`

Comment: No, can be anything from zero to `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity is

```
O(N * V * std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()) = O(N * V)
```

Because `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` is a constant.

Comment: I don't think so, the first posted answer by you seems more correct. There is not always the max int in there, it's a simple user input which might be as high as that. So the `V_max` seems to make sense

Comment: You wrote in the comments: "No, can be anything from zero to std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()"

Comment: Yes, it **can**, but doesn't have to. The maximum element might be even just `4`.

Comment: Yep, then a more refined answer would be the `O(N*V*V_max)`, but the `O(N*V)` still holds, because `V_max = O(1)` since it's limited by the `unsigned int`s precision.

Comment: By the way if you want to put the C++ technicalities aside, the algorithm runs in `O(2^n)` time, because it depends on the input length (n) exponentially.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on `V[j]` if `v[j]=1`, then the complexity will be `O(N*V)` if `V[j]=N` then the complexity will be O(N<sup>2</sup>, V).

Comment: But this is exactly the reason why I ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of this algorithm is unknown. It is akin to following:

```
void foo(int arg) {
   int i = random() - arg;
   for (j = 0; j<i; ++j) 
        do_stuff();
```

Complexity of this foo() can not be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

O(N*v.size()* max(v)) ---> [O(N*v.size()*int.Max)].
note your code maybe is wrong because you are not getting any exception [try v[0] = int.Max]